# Title attribute of <a> in FeedItem is replaced by null

Tags: rest-api, chatter, feeditem

I posted several `FeedItem`s using Salesforce Rest API but the title attribute of `<a>` tags in rich texts were not working correctly for me.

For instance,

```
POST /sobjects/FeedItem/

{
    "ParentId": "5000o0000xxxxxxxxx",
    "Body": "<ol>\n    <li>\n        <a title=\"Google\" href=\"https:\/\/www.google.com\">Google<\/a>\n    <\/li>\n<\/ol>",
    "IsRichText": true
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>
        <a title="Google" href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

...would be parsed into

```html
<ol>
    <li>
        <span dir="ltr" class="uiOutputText"></span>
        <a href="https://www.google.com" title="null" target="_blank"><span dir="ltr" class="uiOutputText">Google</span></a>
        <span dir="ltr" class="uiOutputText"></span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

...and displayed like

[image: Salesforce Chatter comment screenshot]

Any idea what's going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know salesforce provides 2 types of RTE (Rich Text Area) fields.

1. Actually a RTE which has all the components such as adding hyperlink, images etc etc.
2. Secondly, are those such as in feeditems which do not support  the hyperlink, images etc things.

So, this is the reason why the hyperlink isn't showing in feeditems. Instead it's converted into span with target null.

Edit the feeditem you will see a different RTE field as compared to if you have any RTE Field on case or any other object.

Thanks!!!

Comment: The link is showing and works. Only the `title` is `null`. Please read my question carefully, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce Rich text don't support the "title" attribute, basically, when you create a  tag in a FeedItem, the "target" automatically change to "_blank" if "href" isn't empty, but if you use "title" the attribute is removed.

Comment: This answer looks nothing like your previous post, and does actually contain content which answers the question. Your previous post essentially just read "I'm having this problem too," which is why I deleted it.